# Need my vba code to search a value only amongst certain columns

Tags: vba, excel

My question is this, not sure if it can be achieved:(Need to do it with vba)
I have a range with 5 groups of 3 years each (a column for 2012, 2013 and 2014 in each group) these columns have grades. I need to find the highest grade amongst all the groups, but only for the year of 2013. I know how to find the higher grade, but it searches amongst all the columns.
Can I find this grade but make it search only amongst the columns that belong to 2013?

[example of the data range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHfqi.png)

Comment: What does your data look like? A formula wouldn't be acceptable? What have you tried, please post your current code/formulas.

Comment: Added an example image of my data, it has to be on vba, which is too bad because I think I could fix a formula for it :(  as for my current code, I'm honestly clueless, don't know how can I restrict the search to only columns of the same year

Comment: Can you post the code you have too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help you out. This is a quite generic code to do what you are asking. You can extend this by making a UserForm and asking the user what column header you wish to identify rather than only looking for 2013.

```
Sub 
   Dim lastColumn As Long
   Dim max_value As Double

   max_value = 0

   lastColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   For i = 1 To lastColumn
      ' Seek out the column you desire!
      If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,i).Value = "2013" Then

         Dim lastRow As Long
         lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

         ' Go through the entire column of the desired type to read the values
         For j = 3 To lastRow
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Value > max_val Then
               max_value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Value
            End If
         Next j
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! seems like this will work! I think i'll modify it to be color the cell with the result but shouldn't have much problem now!